# Calculate Length Totals in ArcGIS based on field values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, fields-attributes, standard-license-level

I am having trouble finding the right words to describe this problem but here goes:

I have 3 values (120,270,380) in my field called operatingvolt for every segment of conductor. Each segment of conductor has a feederid to identify what system it belongs to. I would like to use ArcGIS to calculate the length of each segment by operatingvolt and feederid.The goal is to get a table that looks like this:

[image]

The problem I run into is that if the feederid does not have an operatingvolt then the length will not be computed. This happens frequently since not every feederid has every operatingvolt value. I would like a length computed for every feederid at every possible operatingvolt even if the length is 0.

I also would like to be able to create a model that completes this task. I have  limited knowledge of python.

Comment: Can you include the calculation required to get the length from your other two fields?  I'm unsure how you get a 'length' from those two values

Comment: There is a separate field for length. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I have tried the summary statistics tool which calculates the total length by feeder id and operatingvolt but any feederid that has no operating voltage value is not included in the table because there is no record. For example if feederid 1 has no 380 operatingvolt then its not included in the final table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this done by creating a model with many tedious steps but it worked. Basically, I selected any Feeders without a certain voltage then merged and summarized the table with the total lengths of each Feeder of that voltage. This gave me a length value for each Feeder.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to obtain the line (vector) segment linear distance.  Project the feature class, add a field and then use the Calculate Geometry function to obtain the length.

Answer (score 1):

With the advanced license you can use the frequency tool to produce the table you want. The analysis fields are feeder and voltage, the summary field is length
Any nulls in either field will be aggregated and reported in the table.

You can add the tool to a model.http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/frequency.htm

Comment: I figured that... I only have an ArcEditor license.

Comment: There is a "Free" frequency tool that will get you there too... arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14667. You should edit your question to include this licensing limitation

Comment: Frequency functionality can be emulated with Basic and Standard level license by using Summary Statistics with Case Fields.

Answer (score 1):

As @PolyGeo comments you can do this with [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) with any license level. Use

- the Length field as statistics field with the 'SUM' statistic type
- the FeederId and OperatingVolt as case fields.

You will get the total length of all combinations of FeederID and OperatingVolt values.

[image]

This is a single step process so I don't see much added value in putting it in a model, nevertheless you can drag and drop the tool in a ModelBuilder and if necessary turn some parameters (input table, output table, statistic fields, case fields) to model parameters, so you can modify them at runtime:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats the method I was using originally but it does not have a record for a FeederID that does not have a voltage. For example if FeederID 1 does not have a voltage of 120 I would like there to be a record in the table for that. I was using modelbuilder with the summary statistics tool because I need to perform other calculations/add fields to the data.